# Import excel data put into the SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

I am tried to import excel data into my MySQL Query browser database. I try to use below the coding type in the MySQL Query to execute, but it cannot work.

My code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
    'c:/2019/countries.csv'
    INTO TABLE countries
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (id,name,country_code,language);
```

The My SQL query browser show me the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ROWS
>         (id,name,country_code,language)' at line 7

[image]

My database info:

[image]

My excel data info (My excel file location is"c:/2019/countries.csv"):

[image]

My CSV file info:

```
  id,name,country_code,language
  231,Andorra,20,en
  232,United Arab Emirates,784,en
  233,Afghanistan,4,en
  234,Antigua and Barbuda,28,en
  235,Anguilla,660,en
  236,Albania,8,en
  237,Armenia,51,en
  238,Angola,24,en
  239,Antarctica,10,en
  240,Argentina,32,en
  241,American Samoa,16,en
```

Anyone can guide me what I get the wrong in my coding? Thanks.

Comment: Help yourself - add the first few lines of csv file to question as text.

Comment: Do note: CSV is not an Excel data type.

Comment: I have save in CSV format

Comment: Also, try escaping your columns names with backticks (notice *language* is blue-highlighted) some are [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-N). These can cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Parfait How I  can know my file is under CSV file? I see the file type is csv

Comment: @P.Salmon I have added few line of csv file

Comment: The csv file added loads fine for me. If you are doing this on a windows box you should change  'c:/2019/countries.csv' to  'c:\\2019\\countries.csv'. and you may need '\r\n' You should also add your table definition.

Comment: @Parfait is version 5.1.73

Comment: @P.Salmon I have use your method change c:\\2019\\countries.csv', but the error is same

Comment: Yup. Very thanks you give a right way for me.   Replace ROWS with LINES is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your MySQL version, `IGNORE` clauses in `LOAD DATA` exclusively uses `LINES` or in latter versions, interchangebaly uses `LINES` or `ROWS`. You can see this by docs of different versions:

**`LINES` and `ROWS` are synonymous**

```
[IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
```

- MySQL 8
- MySQL 5.7: [Load Data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)
- MySQL 5.6: [Load Data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)
- MySQL 5.5: [Load Data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

**Only `LINES` allowed** (i.e., `ROWS` not supported)

```
[IGNORE number LINES]
```

- MySQL 5.4: [Load Data](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.4/en/load-data.html)
- MySQL 5.1: [Load Data](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem (win10)

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int,name varchar(20),country_code int,language varchar(20));

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
    'C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.1\\data\\sandbox\\data.txt'
    INTO TABLE t
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (id,name,country_code,language);

+------+----------------------+--------------+----------+
| id   | name                 | country_code | language |
+------+----------------------+--------------+----------+
|  231 | Andorra              |           20 | en       |
|  232 | United Arab Emirates |          784 | en       |
|  233 | Afghanistan          |            4 | en       |
|  234 | Antigua and Barbuda  |           28 | en       |
|  235 | Anguilla             |          660 | en       |
|  236 | Albania              |            8 | en       |
|  237 | Armenia              |           51 | en       |
|  238 | Angola               |           24 | en       |
|  239 | Antarctica           |           10 | en       |
|  240 | Argentina            |           32 | en       |
|  241 | American Samoa       |           16 | en       |
+------+----------------------+--------------+----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```